# Unusual Joins SQL

Tags: join, sql-server-2012

I am having to convert code written by a former employee to work in a new database. In doing so I came across some joins I have never seen and do not fully understand how they work or if there is a need for them to be done in this fashion.

The joins look like this:

```
From Table A
     Join(Table B
          Join Table C
               on B.Field1 = C.Field1)
          On A.Field1 = B.Field1
```

Does this code function differently from something like this:

```
From Table A
     Join Table B
          On A.Field1 = B.Field1
     Join Table C
          On B.Field1 = C.Field1
```

If there is a difference please explain the purpose of the first set of code.

All of this is done in SQL Server 2012. Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: It's not really unusual.  You are creating a subset of data in the sub query allowing you to perform operations, like groupings, on the subset vs the whole set, as in example two.

Comment: I've always found parenthesis extremely confusing in the from clause (except to delineate derived tables then). Never in my lifetime have I written joins using parenthesis (and I've written many thousands of queries). The parenthesis only serve to confuse. Having said that, the result of the statements are the same. It might force order of joins though, but the optimizer will do as it sees fit anyway. In statements with LEFT/RIGHT/FULL joins that would require some investigation though.

Comment: @SteveMangiameli I am not sure I follow you on doing groupings on just the subset vs the whole set. Since the same field in B is equal to the fields in C and A would not doing groupings on one affect the other in the same manner. The only time i have seen groupings on a subset is when doing a full select statement as the subquery. Although I am still very new to all this. On a side side note is there any reason why people write full Select statements inside a join instead of just making a temp table and joining to that. It seems to me it is much easier to read that way.

Comment: Several reasons, all having to do with resources and performance.  I'll give an example in an answer.

Comment: *"[...]full select statement as the subquery"* >> that's called a derived table for short.

Comment: *"any reason why people write full Select statements inside a join instead of just making a temp table and joining to that."* >> Because derived tables are not necessarily materialized (ie written to disk), temporary tables are explicitely materialized to database `tempdb`. In some cases derived tables offer better performance, in yet other cases a temporary table is warranted because they are explicitely materialized. Comment section is a bit short to explain all that, there are plenty of articles to be found on optimization that will describe this in detail.

Comment: That you for the brief idea and the path to research. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw this kind of joins - it's MS Access style for handling multi-table joins. In MS Access you need to nest each subsequent `join` statement into its level brackets. So, for example this T-SQL join:

```
SELECT a.columna, b.columnb, c.columnc
FROM tablea AS a 
LEFT JOIN tableb AS b ON a.id = b.id 
LEFT JOIN tablec AS c ON a.id = c.id
```

you should convert to this:

```
SELECT a.columna, b.columnb, c.columnc
FROM ((tablea AS a) LEFT JOIN tableb AS b ON a.id = b.id) LEFT JOIN tablec AS c ON a.id = c.id
```

So, yes, I believe you are right in your assumption

Comment: So you are saying that this is likely due to the former employee having a MS Access background. Makes sense.

Comment: It sounds very possible. In my case it was very opposite. I had to write MS Access query having T-SQL background and I was very surprised about these nested joins :)

Comment: [Here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INNER-JOIN-Operation-b9e73ab6-884a-403e-9f22-cb502feae36a) are the rules (at the bottom)

Answer (score 2):

I could create a temp table and then join that.  But why use up the cycles\RAM on additional storage and indexes if I can just do it on the fly?

I ran across this scenario today in SSRS - a user wanted to see all the *Individuals* granted access through an AD group.  The user was using a cursor and some temp tables to get the users out of AD and then joining the user to each SSRS object (Folders, reports, linked reports) associated with the AD group.  I simplified the whole thing with  Cross Apply and a sub query.

**GroupMembers table**

- GroupName
- UserID
- UserName
- AccountType
- AccountTypeDesc

**SSRSOjbects_Permissions table**

- Path
- PathType
- RoleName
- RoleDesc
- Name (AD group name)

The query needs to return each individual in an AD group associated with each report.  Basically a Cartesian product of users to reports within a subset of data. The easiest way to do this looks like this:

```
select 
    G.GroupName, G.UserID, G.Name, G.AccountType, G.AccountTypeDesc,
    [Path], PathType, RoleName, RoleDesc
from 
    GroupMembers G
cross apply 
    (select 
         [Path], PathType, RoleName, RoleDesc 
     from 
         SSRSOjbects_Permissions  
     where 
         Name = G.GroupName) S;
```

You could achieve this with a temp table and some outer joins, but why waste system resources?

Comment: Steve this is amazing this really helps me understand the point of a full select vs temp table. But the more important part here is ever since i have started SQL I have wondered if there was ever a use for Cross Apply. Never seen one with what I have done so far aside from making a fake database to fiddle with. So thanks for the real life use of that even though you did not know I was curious. :)